# Are there any other asterisks in Candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I found the one for the pogo stick, but I thought I saw one for something else. Are there any other asterisks (*) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a text game, you can simply use your browser’s *Find* function.

There are in fact four more asterisks, but they are just part of the castle towers and not special:

[image: Screenshot of browser with Find control open and asterisks highlighted]

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but thanks anyway. At least I know there aren't any more of them. :)

Comment: What were you looking for, the “boots of luck”?

Comment: I was really just thinking that there might be something else important to the game that had to do with an asterisk. I guess not. But thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You may have read about the “boots of luck” and got that stuck in the back of your mind. There’s a myth that somehow spread about another asterisk that leads to the aforementioned boots, but it is total hogwash.

Comment: Ok well thanks. I guess it's true, I had heard of the 'Boots of Luck'.